# Plotly: How to set custom xticks

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

From [plotly doc](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter):

> ***layout > xaxis > tickvals:***
>
> Sets the values at which ticks on this axis
>   appear. Only has an effect if `tickmode` is set to "array". Used with
>   `ticktext`.
>
> ***layout > xaxis > ticktext:***
>
> Sets the text displayed at the
>   ticks position via `tickvals`. Only has an effect if `tickmode` is set
>   to "array". Used with `tickvals`.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
feature = pd.DataFrame({'ds': pd.date_range('20200101', periods=100*24, freq='H'), 
                        'y': np.random.randint(0,20, 100*24) , 
                        'yhat': np.random.randint(0,20, 100*24) , 
                        'price': np.random.choice([6600, 7000, 5500, 7800], 100*24)})


import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)


y = feature.set_index('ds').resample('D')['y'].sum()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=y.index, y=y))


x_dates = y.index.to_series().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').sort_values().unique()


layout = dict(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickmode="array",
        tickvals=np.arange(0, x_dates.shape[0],2).astype(int),
        ticktext=x_dates[::2],
        tickformat='%Y-%m-%d',
        tickangle=45,
    )
)

fig.update_layout(layout)
fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Since length of `x_dates[::2]` is 50 , the ticknumber doesn't match at all .
How do I sovle it ??

Comment: I'm not sure what the intent of the question is, but are you saying you want 50 x-axis labels for every 100 pieces of data?

Comment: @r-beginners I just want to set costom xticks . I know `nticks` can do similar thing in this case, but the problem is why `tickmode="array"` doesn't work .

Comment: You are creating a `layout` `dict`. But you are not passing it to the `fig` object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I normally use the approach below. You should know that `tickvals` is to be regarded as a *positional* argument and works best (perhaps only) with numerical values and not dates. Use `ticktext` to display the dates in your preferred format.

**Snippet 1:**

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45,
                 tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = df_tips['date'][0::40],
                 ticktext= [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in datelist])
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

Now you can change `tickvals=np.arange(0, y.shape[0]).astype(int)[0::40]` to `tickvals=np.arange(0, y.shape[0]).astype(int)[0::80]` and get:

**Plot 2:**

[image: plot2]

So why didn't this work for you the first time? A number of reasons:

1. Your resampled *pandas series* ***y*** had dates as indexes, so `y.index` were set as x-axis values.
2. `y.index` returns *dates*
3. When you set the tickmark *positions* through `fig.update_xaxes(tickvals)`, this works better with *integer* values.

And what did I do to fix it?

1. I reset the index after resampling so that `y.index` does not return dates.
2. Changed y to a dataframe using `.to_frame`.
3. Changed to `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=y.index, y=y.y))` which otherwise would have failed since this is now a dataframe and not a series.
4. Your dates are now retrieved as `x_dates = y.ds`

I know `y=y.y` looks *really* weird, but I just left it like that as a friendly reminder to give your pandas series or dataframes more sensible names than a single letter like `y` that's more likely to be confused with a single, index-free, array or list.

**Complete code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode

# data
np.random.seed(42)
feature = pd.DataFrame({'ds': pd.date_range('20200101', periods=100*24, freq='H'), 
                        'y': np.random.randint(0,20, 100*24) , 
                        'yhat': np.random.randint(0,20, 100*24) , 
                        'price': np.random.choice([6600, 7000, 5500, 7800], 100*24)})

# resampling
y = feature.set_index('ds').resample('D')['y'].sum()#.to_frame()
y=y.to_frame()
y.reset_index(inplace=True)

# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=y.index, y=y.y))

# x-ticks preparations
x_dates = y.ds
tickvals=np.arange(0, y.shape[0]).astype(int)[0::40]
ticktext=x_dates

# update tickmarks
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45,
                 tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = tickvals,
                 ticktext=[d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in ticktext])

fig.show()
```

Comment: Weird, your code is correct in my env, my code still shows wrong xticks,  could you run my code to do a testing ?

Comment: Feed integer values to `x` and `tickvals`, that is right  point . I didn't tried this becasue similar code worked in matplotlib. So it looks like plotly has some problems when handling dtype  `{ 'x' : date, `tickvals`: int }` and dtype   `{ 'x' : date, `tickvals`: date }` , later one didn't work too so that I didn't try  `{ 'x' : int, `tickvals`: int }` . I think I would go to borther the plotly devs : ) .  Thank you for pointing this out  .