# how to control max length of colum names graph in plotly dash

Tags: python, express, plotly, plotly-dash

i have a code like that

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
fig = px.bar(df, y='pop', x='country', text='pop')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2s}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=8, uniformtext_mode='hide')
fig.show()
```

and it builds me this diagram
[image]

how to make max length on colums name?

Comment: You mean `country` name?

Comment: Yes, the lower axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a very similar question & answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505485/how-to-shorten-and-show-only-a-part-of-text-in-plotly-express-axis). Adapted to your case, you could chose to keep only the first *n* letters of the column name. It would look like the following:

```py
import plotly.express as px
# Data
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe' and year == 2007 and pop > 2.e6")
# Figure
fig = px.bar(df, y='pop', x='country', text='pop')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2s}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=8, uniformtext_mode='hide')

# The modification: overwrite tick labels    
# Choose the number of letters to keep
n = 7
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = {
     'tickmode': 'array',
     'tickvals': df.country.unique().tolist(),
     'ticktext': [i[:n] for i in df.country.unique().tolist()],
    }
)
fig.show()
```

For `n=7` it produces:
[image]